# asp.net javascript - change the label text on changing drop down selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net web forms and have an event fired when some drop down selection changes. Event is not in the code behind , instead it is a javascript method that is executed when the event fires. I need to change the text of some label according to the value changed in the dropdown.

I am a newbie to javascript, couldn't find a way to access the "Text" property of the label.
Can someone help pls ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myMethod(sender, args) {

        ............
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a quick example. The most important thing to remember is that aspnet can rename the ID of the element in the generated html. So always use `ClientID`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Item 3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        $('#<%= Label1.ClientID %>').text($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In html you can call the event by putting a event using onchange attribute. you can get the value in JavaScript by using this keyword. for example I make a small demo here https://jsfiddle.net/3nfvy6ke/5/

```
<select onchange="javascript:test(this)">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected>2</option>
</select>
<script>
function test(ele){
debugger;
document.write(ele.value);
}
</script>
```